# PHP MySQL GROUP_CONCAT self join table

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to self join a table for hierarchy purposes but I am stuck with the group_concat that does not want to cooperate well.

```
SELECT 
    c1.client AS parent, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c2.client) AS child 
    FROM clients c1
    LEFT JOIN clients c2 ON 
    c1.client_id = c2.client_relation 
    ORDER BY 
    c1.client_id
```

I want to show the clients that don't have children (NULL), as well. I have fiddle with ifnull, but can't seem to figure it out.

The table should look something like this

```
Parent 1 -> null
Parent 2 -> Child 2.1, Child 2.2
Parent 3 -> null
Parent 4 -> Child 4.1
...
```

Comment: Your query does not contain GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    c1.client AS parent, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c2.client) AS child 
FROM clients c1
LEFT JOIN clients c2 ON 
   c1.client_id = c2.client_relation 
GROUP BY 
   c1.client_id
ORDER BY 
   c1.client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

[Alina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72881605/php-mysql-group-concat-self-join-table/72881983#comment128728247_72881605) that I was simply missing the `GROUP BY`.